# Silktide cookie consent 3.0.3 conflict with Font Awesome 5.0.2 using CSS Pseudo-elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies, font-awesome-5

There seems to be a bug when using this these 2 libraries together and trying to use CSS Pseudo-elements.

I have created a demo here: http://tappetyclick.com/fontawesomebug/. The text in the anchor which has the pseudo-element disappears and I only see the icon

If I remove the cookie consent plugin code then everything seems to work as expected see http://tappetyclick.com/fontawesomebug/test.htm

Has anyone else seen this issue or know what might be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I could be massively wrong, this is just a guess.

I think this is happening because cookie consent defines the `aria-labelledby` attr as `cookieconsent:desc` but the `:` is the pseudo element selector, therefor it is trying to find a `:desc` pseudo selector (which clearly doesn't exist).

You *MIGHT* be able to stop this error by defining it in jQuery

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
  // add the :desc pseudo-selector to jQuery
  desc: function (el, index, selector) {
    // stub for now
    return false;
  }
});
```

or what ever selector library you may be using.

Thats my best guess at least